# I add pagination in my data table but table records are repeating

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, datatable

In my pagination code fetch data from table its shows data search and pagination are working but records are shows multiple times

[image]

In above image you can see reparation of records.

Controller :

```
       public function getData(){ 
           $postData = $this->input->post();
           $data = $this->dispatchModel->viewData($postData);
           echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model:

```
function viewData($postData=null){
     $response = array();
     ## Read value
     $draw            = $postData['draw'];
     $start           = $postData['start'];
     $rowperpage      = $postData['length']; // Rows display per page
     $columnIndex     = $postData['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
     $columnName      = $postData['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
     $columnSortOrder = $postData['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
     $searchValue     = $postData['search']['value']; // Search value

     ## Search 
     $searchQuery = "";
     if($searchValue != ''){

        $searchQuery = " (b.disp_ch_driver like'%".$searchValue."%') ";
     }

     ## Total number of records without filtering
     $this->db->select('count(*) as allcount');
     $records = $this->db->get('dispatch_challan')->result();
     $totalRecords = $records[0]->allcount;

     ## Total number of record with filtering
     $this->db->select('count(*) as allcount');
     if($searchValue != '')
        $this->db->where($searchQuery);
     $records = $this->db->get('dispatch_challan b')->result();
     $totalRecordwithFilter = $records[0]->allcount;

     ## Fetch records
     $this->db->select('vn.vehicle_no as vehicle,bn.branch_name as from_branch_name,bn1.branch_name as to_branch_name,b.*,vn.*,bn.*,bn1.*');
             $this->db->from('dispatch_challan b');
             $this->db->join('vehicle vn', 'b.disp_ch_lorryno=vn.vehicle_id','left');
             $this->db->join('branch  bn', 'b.disp_ch_from=bn.branch_id','left');
             $this->db->join('branch  bn1','b.disp_ch_to=bn1.branch_id','left');

             $this->db->where('b.status','active');

     if($searchValue != '')
     $this->db->where($searchQuery);
     $this->db->order_by($columnName, $columnSortOrder);
     $this->db->limit($rowperpage, $start);
     $records = $this->db->get('dispatch_challan')->result();

     $data = array();
     foreach($records as $record ){
        $data[] = array( 
           "disp_ch_no"          =>$record->disp_ch_no,
           "disp_ch_date"        =>$record->disp_ch_date,
           "from_branch_name"    =>$record->from_branch_name,
           "to_branch_name"      =>$record->to_branch_name,
           "vehicle"             =>$record->vehicle,
           "disp_ch_pan"         =>$record->disp_ch_pan,
           "disp_ch_driver"      =>$record->disp_ch_driver,
           "disp_ch_owner"       =>$record->disp_ch_owner,
           "disp_ch_remark"      =>$record->disp_ch_remark
        ); 
     }
     ## Response
     $response = array(
        "draw" => intval($draw),
        "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecords,
        "aaData" => $data
     );
     return $response; 
   }
```

In above model have pagination code its working but records are shows multiple times.
In my data base I have only 5 records.

Comment: The quick "fix" seams `DISTINCT` , but the real question is why the duplication happens.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Also you should provide the query which codeigniter is generating i believe there is a `get_compiled_select()` function to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

issue may be database query not in table pagination, because of joins. try to run the model or api using postman and observe the result there it is repeating or not.